# Socket Data Format

Tags: c#, android, sockets

I am using the following code section in android to send data:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                true);

byte[] bytes = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
out.println(bytes);
out.flush();
```

and in receiving portion, I am using:

```
byte[] buffer = (byte[])obj[0];
handler = (Socket)obj[1];
string content = string.Empty;
int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);
content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
```

Now in receiving portion, I believe I am getting references (output: [B@2ec1156f). any suggestion to solve this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the input as well? (what `str` is)

Comment: str contains the string that I am sending to C# server

Comment: I know *what* it contains, but can you give us an *example* of what it contains. Preferably the same value that produced the output you described.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly: 
String str = et.getText().toString();
Log.d("String", str); shows the exact text that I am typing on the textbox

Comment: I don't think you are getting it, does `str = "apples"`, or what is the actual value being sent over the network by the android application. I don't need to know how its formed, just the actual value it contains.

Comment: Your receiving code does not make sense. Nor your output. Do you really think we can see what that code does? It't far from code normally used. So you should start explaining how it works.